# c# button click on new form takes long time to load

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a button click to pop up a new form, and it is taking a while to load up. the following is my

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CashPOS
{
   public partial class SubItems : Form
   {
      CashSales cashSalesForm;
      List<string> itemList= new List<String>();
      public SubItems()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         addItemToList();
         getMainFormInfo();
      }

      private void getMainFormInfo()
      {
         cashSalesForm = new CashSales();
         createItemBtn(itemList, subItemPanel, itemBtnClicked);
      }

      private void addItemToList()
      {
         itemList.Add("abc12");
         itemList.Add("abc13");
         itemList.Add("abc14");
         itemList.Add("abc15");
         itemList.Add("abc16");
         itemList.Add("abc17");
         itemList.Add("abc18");
         itemList.Add("abc19");
         itemList.Add("abc20");
         itemList.Add("abc21");
         itemList.Add("abc22");
         itemList.Add("abc23");
         itemList.Add("abc24");
         itemList.Add("abc25");
         itemList.Add("abc26");
         itemList.Add("abc27");
         itemList.Add("abc28");
         itemList.Add("abc29");
         itemList.Add("abc30");
         itemList.Add("abc31");
         itemList.Add("abc32");
         itemList.Add("abc33");
         itemList.Add("abc34");
         itemList.Add("abc35");
         itemList.Add("abc36");
         itemList.Add("abc37");
         itemList.Add("abc38");
         itemList.Add("abc39");
      }

      protected void itemBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         float unitPrice = 0.0f;
         Button btn = sender as Button;
         string itemSelected = btn.Text;
      }

      public void createItemBtn(List<String> itemList, Control panel, EventHandler handler)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
         {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Width = 203;
            newButton.Height = 132;
            newButton.AutoSize = false;
            newButton.Name = "newBtn" + i;
            newButton.Text = itemList[i].ToString();
            // btnList.Add(newButton);
            panel.Controls.Add(newButton);
         }        
      }
   }
}
```

this is the form that open from the following button click event

```
protected void itemBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   string itemSelected = btn.Text;
   SubItems sub = new SubItems();
   sub.Show();
}
```

i am not sure if the createItemBtn is delaying it by alot, because when I remove this function, it would open the form instantly, but with this function, it takes around 1.5 second to open the form. Is there a better way to reduce the time for this?

Comment: Pause the debugger while it's frozen and look at the stack trace to see what it's doing,

Comment: @SLaks its not really frozen, it just takes a little longer to create the form, i would like it to open the form instantly which works without the createItemBtn function

Comment: So pause it during that time.

Comment: You're also creating a CashSales form and not doing anything with it.  What kind of panel is that?  If it's the plain one, every button is on top of each other.

Comment: That `createItemBtn()` doesn't seem to be resources greedy. Wouldn't it be a bit faster to generate the whole list of `Button` and use then `panel.Controls.AddRange();` (or yield return Button) ?

Comment: @Cid i am gonna give it a try and see if it gets a bit faster. thank you

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `EventHandler handler`. Why using it?

Comment: You need to also post the code for this form: `CashSales`.

Comment: Put breakpoint just on`InitializeComponent()`. When you do that, start you form and breakpoint will hit. In diagnostic tools on right side you will have column `Duration` to see how long it takes for line to execute. Now press F10 to step over. It will add new line with new duration value. See what line causes longest to  do. When you see that tell me what line is it. Remember, last item in Diagnostic tool is value for current line you are on (where yellow -> is pointing)

Comment: `private void getMainFormInfo() { cashSalesForm = new CashSales(); }`. Is this supposed to reference another Form? It won't work and it's probably what is delaying the current Form loading.

Comment: You have this code `cashSalesForm = new CashSales();`  but you don't show that code.  I'm guessing that is where the slowdown is.